# Electron - BrowserWindow minWidth not respected on windows

Tags: electron

Anyone experiencing the same issue? On linux/mac the code below works perfectly, but on windows the browser window is ~14px under the specified minWidth which adds a horizontal scrollbar when it should not be there.

Just using this code you can see the issue. (Note you can put any url in there or take out the webview and just put some content, its always under the specified minWidth)

Here is Main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

app.on('window-all-closed', () => { app.quit(); });

app.on('ready', () => {

    mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 600,
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 400
    });
    mainWin.loadURL('file://`' + __dirname + './index.html');
});
```

Here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
       html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
       body {
         display: flex;
         flex-flow: column;
         background: #ddd;
       }

       webview { flex: 1; }
    </style>
    <body>
      <webview src="www.github.com"></webview>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about with `useContentSize: true`?

Comment: Wow that worked. I filed a bug with electron that the minWidth is not respected but will be using this in the mean time. Thanks

Comment: this may be the intended behavior, but devs will tell their standpoint on this in your issue ;) for future references: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12755